# Obj-C return to a block from a delegate method?

Tags: objective-c

I'm writing a mac app that runs its own web server, using the GCDWebServer library (https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer). My app delegate handles GET requests like so:

```
 __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
 [webServer addDefaultHandlerForMethod:@"GET"
          requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class]
          processBlock:^GCDWebServerResponse *(GCDWebServerRequest* request) {

              return [weakSelf handleRequest:request];

          }];
```

And then the handleRequest method returns the response data, something like:

```
return [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithHTML:@"<html><body><p>Hello World!</p></body></html>"];
```

So far so good. Except now I want the handleRequest method to use NSSpeechSynthesizer to create an audio file with some spoken text in it, and then wait for the speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking method to be called before returning to the processBlock.

```
// NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate method:
- (void)speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender didFinishSpeaking:(BOOL)success
{
    NSLog(@"did finish speaking, success: %d", success);
    // return to processBlock...
}
```

Problem is, I have no idea how to do this. Is there a way to return from the speechSynthesizer:didFinishSpeaking method into the processBlock defined above?

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the speech synthesizer on a separate thread with its own run loop, and use a lock to allow your request thread to wait for the operation to complete on the speech thread.

Assuming the web server maintains its own thread(s) and runloop, you can use your app's main thread to run the speech synthesizer, and you can use `NSCondition` to signal completion to the web response thread.

A basic (untested) example (without error handling):

```
@interface SynchroSpeaker : NSObject<NSSpeechSynthesizerDelegate>
- (id)initWithText:(NSString*)text outputUrl:(NSURL*)url;
- (void)run;
@end

@implementation SynchroSpeaker
{
    NSCondition* _lock;
    NSString* _text;
    NSURL* _url;
    NSSpeechSynthesizer* _synth;
}

- (id)initWithText:(NSString*)text outputUrl:(NSURL*)url
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _text = text;
        _url = url;
        _lock = [NSCondition new];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)run
{
    NSAssert(![NSThread isMainThread], @"This method cannot execute on the main thread.");
    [_lock lock];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(startOnMainThread) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
    [_lock wait];
    [_lock unlock];
}

- (void)startOnMainThread
{
    NSAssert([NSThread isMainThread], @"This method must execute on the main thread.");
    [_lock lock];

    //
    // Set up your speech synethsizer and start speaking
    //
}

- (void)speechSynthesizer:(NSSpeechSynthesizer *)sender didFinishSpeaking:(BOOL)success

{
    //
    // Signal waiting thread that speaking has completed
    //
    [_lock signal];
    [_lock unlock];
}

@end
```

It's used like so:

```
- (id)handleRequest:(id)request
{
    SynchroSpeaker* speaker = [[SynchroSpeaker alloc] initWithText:@"Hello World" outputUrl:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/tmp/foo.dat"]];
    [speaker run];

    ////

    return response;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it looks promising, although it also looks like my web server is running on the main thread, so it crashes on the first NSAssert. :(

Comment: @jkira That sucks.  You'll need to create your own NSThread for the speech synthesizer then.  This thread will run its own NSRunLoop, and instead of using `-performSelectorOnMainThread:` you use [`-performSelector:onThread:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelector:onThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:) and pass in the thread.

Answer (score 0):

GCDWebServer does run into its own threads (I guess 2 of them) - not in the main one. My solution needed to run code in Main Thread when calling the ProcessBlock.

I found this way that suits my needs:

1. First declare a weak storage for my AppDelegate: `__weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;`. Doing so I can access all my properties within the block.
2. Declare a strong reference to AppDelegate from within the block like so:  `__strong AppDelegate* strongSelf = weakSelf;`
3. Use NSOperationQueue to align the operation on mainThread:

   ```
   [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

                                   //Your code goes in here
                                   NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");
                                   [strongSelf myMethodOnMainThread];

                               }];
   ```

In this way `myMethodOnMainThread` surely will run where it's supposed to.

For sake of clarity I quote my relevant code section:

```
webServer = [[GCDWebServer alloc] init];
webServer.delegate = self;

__weak AppDelegate *weakSelf = self;

// Add a handler to respond to GET requests
[webServer addDefaultHandlerForMethod:@"GET"
                         requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class]
                    asyncProcessBlock:^(GCDWebServerRequest* request, GCDWebServerCompletionBlock completionBlock) {

    __strong AppDelegate* strongSelf = weakSelf;
    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^ {

                                    //Your code goes in here
                                    NSLog(@"Main Thread Code");
                                    [strongSelf myMethodOnMainThread];

                                }];

    GCDWebServerDataResponse* response = [GCDWebServerDataResponse responseWithJSONObject:packet];
                                completionBlock(response);


}];
```

Answer (score 0):

GCWebServer supports fully asynchronous responses as of version 3.0 and later [1].

```
[webServer addDefaultHandlerForMethod:@"GET"
                         requestClass:[GCDWebServerRequest class]
                    asyncProcessBlock:^(GCDWebServerRequest* request, GCDWebServerCompletionBlock completionBlock) {

  // 1. Trigger speech synthesizer on main thread (or whatever thread it has to run on) and save "completionBlock"
  // 2. Have the delegate from the speech synthesizer call "completionBlock" when done passing an appropriate response

}];
```

[1] https://github.com/swisspol/GCDWebServer#asynchronous-http-responses